# Allocating a Spritefont into an Class

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm trying to make an allocation of a **Spritefont** to an Spritefont in a class like showing above so that I don't have to pass SpriteFonts and Stuff every single time,  but everytime I try to Render with the `Test_Font` there is an `null-exeption` that the Engine.`Test_Font` is empty. I know that SpriteFont is an Sealed class but when I try to alloc Spritefonts in the mainprogramm it works?!

Thanks a lot!

P.S: Sorry for my English :)

```
class Engine
SpriteFont Test_Font; 
public void Set_Engine(SpriteFont sf)
{
Test_Font = sf;
}
public void Render(SpriteBatch sb)
{
sb.DrawString(Test_Font, "Test", new Vector2(100, 100), Color.Red);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i figured it out, you can´t pass things which aren´t loaded yet. *facepalm*
Just moving the allocation BEHIND the Loading-Sequence and it works. Sometimes i feel Stupid.

Have a nice Day.